# React import external javascript returning error

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm new to React and I'm trying to include a library javascript file to my project. I add the script in the index.html.

```
...
<body>
...
...
<script src="../src/assets/js/scripts-init/demo.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

When I open it in Firefox, I can see the warning and error in the console log.
Warning:

```
The script from “http://localhost:3000/src/assets/js/scripts-init/demo.js” was loaded even though its MIME type (“text/html”) is not a valid JavaScript MIME type.
```

Error:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: expected expression, got '<'  demo.js
```

What's the correct way to add .js script in React project?

Thanks.

Including the demo.js

```
// Demo Theme Options

$(function () {

    $('.btn-open-options').click(function () {
        $('.ui-theme-settings').toggleClass('settings-open');
    });

    $('.close-sidebar-btn').click(function () {

        var classToSwitch = $(this).attr('data-class');
        var containerElement = '.app-container';
        $(containerElement).toggleClass(classToSwitch);

        var closeBtn = $(this);

        if (closeBtn.hasClass('is-active')) {
            closeBtn.removeClass('is-active');
        } else {
            closeBtn.addClass('is-active');
        }
    });

    $('.switch-container-class').on('click', function () {

        var classToSwitch = $(this).attr('data-class');
        var containerElement = '.app-container';
        $(containerElement).toggleClass(classToSwitch);

        $(this).parent().find('.switch-container-class').removeClass('active');
        $(this).addClass('active');

    });

    $('.switch-theme-class').on('click', function () {

        var classToSwitch = $(this).attr('data-class');
        var containerElement = '.app-container';

        if (classToSwitch == 'app-theme-white') {
            $(containerElement).removeClass('app-theme-gray');
            $(containerElement).addClass(classToSwitch);
        }

        if (classToSwitch == 'app-theme-gray') {
            $(containerElement).removeClass('app-theme-white');
            $(containerElement).addClass(classToSwitch);
        }

        if (classToSwitch == 'body-tabs-line') {
            $(containerElement).removeClass('body-tabs-shadow');
            $(containerElement).addClass(classToSwitch);
        }

        if (classToSwitch == 'body-tabs-shadow') {
            $(containerElement).removeClass('body-tabs-line');
            $(containerElement).addClass(classToSwitch);
        }

        $(this).parent().find('.switch-theme-class').removeClass('active');
        $(this).addClass('active');

    });

    $('.switch-header-cs-class').on('click', function () {
        var classToSwitch = $(this).attr('data-class');
        var containerElement = '.app-header';

        $('.switch-header-cs-class').removeClass('active');
        $(this).addClass('active');

        $(containerElement).attr('class', 'app-header');
        $(containerElement).addClass('header-shadow ' + classToSwitch);

    });

    $('.switch-sidebar-cs-class').on('click', function () {
        var classToSwitch = $(this).attr('data-class');
        var containerElement = '.app-sidebar';

        $('.switch-sidebar-cs-class').removeClass('active');
        $(this).addClass('active');

        $(containerElement).attr('class', 'app-sidebar');
        $(containerElement).addClass('sidebar-shadow ' + classToSwitch);

    });
});
```

Comment: post the demo.js content

Comment: I just added it

Comment: Remove the comment from the top of the file and add type="text/javascript> to your script tag

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using static files, you should add them into the public folder in your react project, for example:

```
YOUR_PROJECT_FOLDER
|_public
  |_index.html
  |_static
    |_scripts-init
      |_demo.js
```

And then just refer to it with relative path, like:

```
<script src="/static/scripts-init/demo.js"></script>
```

This is because the code gets transpiled by webpack (or the default transpiler) and generates a dev build where the 'src' folder does not exist.

Comment: Thank you. Should I add all the static files to the public folder?

Comment: Yes, every static file should be inside the public folder structure or hosted in a cdn